# How to pass RGBQUAD as parameter?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio

As a learning excersize, I'm trying to pass a RGBQUAD as a parameter to a method which just blackens the struct members. The program crashes when 'black_quad' is called. Where am I going wrong?

```
void UpdateFields() 
{
    RGBQUAD quad;
    black_quad(&quad);
    /* snip */
}

void black_quad(RGBQUAD* quad) 
{
    quad->rgbBlue = 0;
    quad->rgbGreen = 0;
    quad->rgbRed = 0;
}
```

Comment: Describe what you know and we cannot see.  What does the crash look like?

Comment: "*Where am I going wrong?*"  Nowhere in the code presented.  Can you provide some context?

Comment: As written exactly above, it should not crash.  Now, did you write it exactly like that, or have you simplified it?  For example, maybe `quad` is actually passed into `UpdateFields` by pointer, and at runtime the pointer is either `NULL` or invalid in some way?

Comment: well, when i comment out the call to black_quad, the program runs fine, when it's not commented out, the program will run, and crash as if there was a buffer overflow, windows error reporting window pops up..

Comment: What happens when you debug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to say - your problem lies elsewhere, it seems.
Following code tested and working win7 gcc 4.7.??

```
#include <windows.h>

void black_quad(RGBQUAD* quad)
{
    quad->rgbBlue = 0;
    quad->rgbGreen = 0;
    quad->rgbRed = 0;
}
void UpdateFields()
{
    RGBQUAD quad;
    black_quad(&quad);
}

int main()
{
    UpdateFields();
}
```